# Docker difference between two containers

Tags: docker, docker-container

How do I find the difference between two running containers using Docker client?  I have an image running as multiple instances and later I have changed/installed new packages in the instances and lost track. Is there a way I can find the differences between these running containers?

Comment: How about: export both containers, untar them and run a diff, does that help? If that is not what you are after, please provide more information.

Comment: Sure, that would be one way. But is there a better way or some automated way as a command or tool?

Comment: No issues. I found a tool but seems to be commercial one. Guess there is a free version too. Not sure I can name the tool here. But there are tools available.

Comment: Yes, I also want to do something like `docker diff 289addf309e9..070b76b9aeac`, like what git can do. But looks like docker doesn't support this

Comment: @user88975 you can name the tool here. Please do...

Answer (score 7):

you must inspect container

```
docker inspect CONTAINER_1
docker inspect CONTAINER_2
```

find the fragment for each one

"Id": "cc502eeb69968c9b80c029f8124333d725ee124db4357de69786bc9bdf3a8088",

then with the tow ID you can compare the folders

> /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/CONTAINER_1 vs /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/CONTAINER_2

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the [docker diff](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/diff) command which lists changes made on a container filesystem since it was created.

Take this example in which a new container named *so-26230214* is created, then the file `/tmp/foo.txt` is added and finally `/etc/default/ntpdate` removed:

```
$ docker run -it --name so-26230214 base bash -il
root@b33340ce7b9f:/# echo "foo" > /tmp/foo.txt
root@b33340ce7b9f:/# rm /etc/default/ntpdate
root@b33340ce7b9f:/# logout
```

The `docker diff` command prints out:

```
$ docker diff so-26230214
C /etc
C /etc/default
D /etc/default/ntpdate
C /root
A /root/.bash_history
C /tmp
A /tmp/foo.txt
```

detailling what files were **C**hanged, **A**dded or **D**eleted.

If you need details about what changed in those files, then you have no other choice than exporting the container filesystem with [docker export](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export) or individual files with [docker cp](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp) and examine them.

Note that `docker export` and `docker cp` will only show you files which are part of the container file system, as a result those commands won't give you access to files in [volumes](http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/).

Comment: Thomas, Correct me if I am wrong. Can I use docker diff to do a diff on two different running containers? My question is abount inter-container diff not intra-container diff. Will Docker diff works on inter-containers?

Comment: no it won't, `docker diff` shows you changes to a container file system. While it will not show you the differences between two containers it can help identifying which container has the changes you are looking for. To compare two containers, use `docker export <my_container> > my_container.tar` to produce a tar archive for both containers and then compare the tar files